# Postgresql - Array_remove for elements from select

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a column (members) with an array that has a varying number of elements.

e.g.

```
id   members (integer[])
1    {1, 3, 5, 7}
2    {4, 5, 7, 9}
```

I have a table (unwanted_members) with members that I want removed if they exist, e.g.

```
member
1
7
```

I want to remove these members from the arrays, i.e.

```
id  members
1   {3, 5}
2   {4, 5, 9}
```

Can anyone suggest a simple methodology?

Comment: What is the data type of your `members` column? Please show your table definition.

Comment: Hi Shuwn - it's INTEGER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install the [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) extension this is quite easy:

```
select id, members - (select array_agg(member) from unwanted_members)
from foo;
```

To update the table you can use:

```
update foo
    set members = members - (select array_agg(member) from unwanted_members);
```

---

Without that extension, you first need to unnest the member IDs remove the unwanted and then aggregate them back to an array:

```
select f.id, array_agg(t.mid order by t.idx) as members
from foo f, unnest(f.members) with ordinality as t(mid,idx)
where t.mid not in (select member from unwanted_members)
group by f.id;
```

To update the existing values, use this:

```
update foo
  set members = x.members
from (
  select f.id, array_agg(t.mid order by t.idx) as members
  from foo f, unnest(f.members) with ordinality as t(mid,idx)
  where t.mid not in (select id from unwanted_members)
  group by f.id
) x
where foo.id = x.id;
```

Assuming `id` is the primary key of the table.

Answer (score 2):

@a_horse_with_no_name solution is perfect if extension intarray is available. If not, then you can use a table operators for some operations `UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_remove(anyarray, anyarray)
RETURNS anyarray AS $$
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT unnest($1) EXCEPT SELECT unnest($2))
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

postgres=> select array_remove(ARRAY[1, 3, 5, 7],ARRAY[1,7]);
┌──────────────┐
│ array_remove │
╞══════════════╡
│ {3,5}        │
└──────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name's answer is guaranteed to preserve order since it uses `with ordinality` - is this answer also guaranteed to preserve order due to how it is implemented internally, or not guaranteed?